# Como criar um contador na detecção de face?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Como vocês podem ver no codigo abaixo, ele apenas detecta as faces com haar cascade, gostaria de saber como q faço para exibir na webcam a quantidade de pessoas detectadas no momento.

```
from  __future__ import print_function #importa a funcao da biblioteca future
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #webcam

 face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

while (cap.isOpened()):
ret,frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #faz a conversao pra cinza por ser mais leve pro pc
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5, flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,minSize=(50, 50), maxSize=None)

if len(faces) > 0:
    print("Pessoa detectada!")
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 10, y - 20), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = frame[y-15:y + h+10, x-10:x + w+10]

    cv2.imshow("imagem", frame) #mostra a face detectada
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): # q definido para sair do projeto
    break #para o programa

cap.release() #mostra as coordenadas da deteccao
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Pelo nome, `len(faces)` já é a quantidade de pessoas detectadas, então não entendi exatamente qual é a dúvida.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Por exemplo, vai detectar e mostrar num canto da tela a quantidade de pessoas q foram detectadas: x pessoas detectadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acredito que seja isto que esteja procurando...

```
text = "{} face(s) found".format(len(faces))
cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Total de Pessoas: {}'.format(len(faces)))
```